# Break point at start of any procedure that runs?

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA project has several event based procedures. I know that one of them is running unexpectedly and causing problems, but I don't know which one. I don't want to go though the hassle of creating breakpoints at the start of each and every procedure.

Is it possible to tell the code to stop at the first line that start running, regardless of what procedure it is in?

Comment: Do you mean stop like `exit sub` or pause?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that.

Comment: WHen the problem arises, debug and view call stack?

Comment: @DavidZemens: It doesn't necessarily throw an error. It can be that something happens and I suspect that a macro is the culprit. So I would like VBa to automatically go into debug mode if any line is executed.